# UX Research: Tree Test with profile picture menu

Tags: user-research, information-architecture, tree, ux-research

I would like to do a Tree Test for a site (using UserTesting.com) but one of the nodes in my tree would be a profile picture in the top right of the screen that clicks open to reveal a menu. It's similar to the Google.com screenshot below where clicking the profile picture reveals a menu–the site I'm testing just has the user's name next to their profile picture in the top right. The issue is, Tree Tests only allow the researcher to input text in each node, not pictures (since they don't show the participant any UI). How are you supposed to represent a profile picture menu within a Tree Test? I can't be the only one who has faced this issue. Will I have to instead revert to a usability test or first click test? (Neither of those seem ideal for various reasons for my goals.) Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know that **Tree Tests** typically have limitations when representing visual elements like profile pictures and menus, let's assume you have the technical knowledge to proceed with some technical terms.

There's no actual way to represent a profile picture menu within a Tree Test. However, you can convey the essence of a profile picture menu within your Tree Test structure. Here are the two known ways.

**Leverage the use of textual description:**

Clearly describe the profile picture and menu functionality in the corresponding node.
You could say something like, "Click to open a menu; top right corner: profile picture (displays user's name)."
Without depending on images, this method conveys important information.

**Another way is to use annotations.**

Although embedded photos are not permitted in the tree structure of UserTesting, you can still make use of the annotation feature.
Write a brief description of the profile picture and menu function in the text area. Then, attach a static image of a profile picture and menu structure that is similar using the annotation feature.
In this manner, while they navigate the tree, participants can consult the visual to better grasp the element.